# Iterar registros comprobando tabla relacionada - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenos días quiero iterar una base de datos, pero comprobando una tabla relacionada.

**Vivienda**

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Reformado con plaza de garaje incluida | v-849-reformado-con-plaza-de-garaje-incluida |
| 2 | Reformado con ascensor | v-850-reformado-con-ascensor |

**Likes**

| id | entrie_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 256 |

**Users**

| id | name | rol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mariano | 0 |
| 2 | Roberta | 1 |

Esta es mi consulta a la base de datos que ya tiene más de una relación:

```
$viviendas = Vivienda::query()
                     ->with('etiqueta')
                     ->with('poblacion')
                     ->with('elDistrito')
                     ->with('galeria')
                     ->where('tipo_id', 1)
                     ->where('home', 1)
                     ->where('conectado', 1)
                     ->limit(4)
                     ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                     ->get();
```

Entonces esto son card de propiedades (pisos, garajes, locales, etc.) En cada tarjeta hay un icono de corazón para poder añadirlo a favorito. Entonces lo que quiero es que cuando itero todas las propiedades, que el corazón salga marcado si es que está almacenado en la tabla de `favoritos`.

Hay que decir que solo pueden guardar a favoritos los usuarios registrados, por eso guardo también el usuario en la tabla, pero no se como ejecutar esta query.

**Cuando itero los registros los hago así**

```
@foreach ($viviendas as $item)

  ......
  <i class="far fa-heart"></i> /*Este es el simbolo de corazón que tiene que cambiar si existe en esa base de datos por fas fa-heart*/

@endforeach
```

No se como se como comprobar antes de iterarlo.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes almacenado el `id` del usuario que ha iniciado sesión? Por cierto, en los datos de ejemplo que has proporcionado no hay relación alguna entre ningún usuario, favorito e inmueble. ¿Podrías confirmar las siguientes relaciones? ¿`Users.id` está relacionado con `Favoritos.cliente_id` y `Vivienda.id` con `Favoritos.inmueble_id`? No veo las relaciones en ninguno de los `with` que proporcionas en la consulta.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia no almaceno en ningún sitio el `id` del usuario pero se puede utilizar `{{ auth()->user()->id }}` . Por otro lado la columna `cliente_id` esta relacionada con la `id` de tabla `users` y la columna `inmueble_id` esta relacionada con `id` de la tabla `Viviendas`

Comment: ¿Y no has indicado esa relación en eloquent?

Comment: No, por que no se me ocurre como he de hacerlo para comprobarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico mi propia respuesta.

**Primero creo las rutas para hacer like o dislike**

```
Route::get('/disLike', "Web@disLike")->name('web.disLike');
Route::put('/darLike', "Web@darLike")->name('web.darLike');
```

**En mi controlador, para iterar todas las propiedades**

```
//Antes de esto hay que comprobar si es un usuario invitado
...consulta de la pregunta
$likes = Like::select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
$likeArr = Arr::flatten($likes->toArray());
```

**En la vista de las propiedades:**

```
//Primero compruebo si es un usuario invitado, si es que si lo mando al login
@if(auth()->guest())
   <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="posCora" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" id="{{ $item->id }}" style="color: #333;">
      <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
   </a>
@else
   //Compruebo si ese usuario tiene esa propiedad en likes, si es así le muestro el corazón rojo y posibilidad de hacer dislike, en caso contrario va a la ruta de hacer like
   @if(in_array($item->id,$likes))
      <a class="disLike entrie_{{ $item->id }} posCora" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" id="{{ $item->id }}">
        <i class="far fa-heart" style="color: red;"></i>
      </a>
   @else
      <a class="darLike entrie_{{ $item->id }} posCora" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" id="{{ $item->id }}">
        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
      </a>
   @endif
@endif
```

**Luego mis AJAX para el like y dislike**
Supongo que esta parte se puede hacer con una unica función, pero no se bien hacerla.

```
$(document).on('click', '.darLike', function(){
  var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
  let url = '/darLike/';
   $.ajax({
     headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
     type: "put",
     url: url,
     data: {
       'post_id' : post_id,
       'user_id' : user_id
     },
     success: function(data){
        $(".cuore_"+ post_id +"").load(location.href + " .cuore_"+ post_id +"");
     }
     });         
    return false;
    });

$(document).on('click', '.disLike', function(){
 var post_id = $(this).attr("id");
 var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
 let url = '/disLike/';
 $.ajax({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
   type: "get",
   url: url,
   data: {
     'post_id' : post_id,
     'user_id' : user_id
   },
   success: function(data){
      $(".cuore_"+ post_id +"").load(location.href + " .cuore_"+ post_id +"");
     }
     });         
    return false;
   });
```

**Y por último en el controlador las funciones de like y dislike**

```
public function darLike(Request $request)
    {
        $addLike = new Like;
        $addLike->entrie_id = $request->post_id;
        $addLike->user_id = $request->user_id;

        $addLike->save();
    }

public function disLike(Request $request)
    {
        $dislike = Like::where('entrie_id', $request->post_id)->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
        $dislike->delete();
    }
```

**Si quiero iterar las propiedades que tiene un usuario**

```
$likes = Like::with('viviendas')->select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

@forelse ($likes as $item) 
   @foreach ($item->viviendas as $item2)
    ......
   @endforeach
@empty
   No tienes favoritos
@endforelse
```